# Moved wordpress to subdirectory - images not showing - relink?

Tags: image, wordpress, .htaccess, subdirectory

I'm not a wordpress person - but I had to move Wordpress to a subdirectory from root for a person the other day.

I followed the steps on the Wordpress site - and everything transferred fine.  All the articles, logins, etc. display fine.

The issue is the images in the articles - they are linking to the old address (from root: www.domain.com/link/to/image); the images are now in a subdirectory (www.domain.com/blog/link/to/image)

What is the best way to resolve that?  Obviously going into each article and re-linking would solve the issue but is there an easier, less time-intensive way?  .htaccess?  some other bit of coding that would be helpful?  Again, I'm not a wordpress guy so I'm not sure what would be the best way to do this but I would think there has to be something besides manually going through blog posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried going to:
Settings in WP-Admin >> Media Settings 
Then try changing both:

"Store uploads in this folder"  Default is wp-content/uploads
"Full URL path to files"    Configuring this is optional. By default, it should be blank.

This should do the trick

Comment: Yea, I just tried that but had no dice.  Does that change existing links that have been placed in articles?

Comment: I marked this as the answer because in the future I'll recommend people do that and keep WP in it's own directory from the start!

Comment: This worked, though I had to re-attach each image from the media library to whatever page they were on. Thanks!

Comment: I should also say I removed the Full URL path to files: "/wp-content/uploads" from the Media settings before I started re-attaching images

Answer (score 0):

[Search RegEx](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-regex/) is a good plugin to be able to search and replace with Grep through all posts and pages.